# How to use expressjs in a NodeJS/ES6/Typescript app

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, ecmascript-6

If my information is correct i need to import dependencies
using `import .. from '..'` instead of `var .. = require('..')` in a ES6 application.

So i changed the imports. But i have problem with the import of the cookie-parser receiving the error

> Module '\"cookie-parser\"' has no default export."

I changed

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
```

to

```
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
```

### How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Was this issue resolved?

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
```

It will work only if you'll also install the types.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/cookie-parser
```

You can then use it like so:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
```

... following [this recommendation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3337).

Answer (score 1):

```
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
```

This should work. Id also make sure you are using the babel transpiler for node. If you aren't using babel the module will fail to load properly

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still facing this issue,

Apart from installing the required types for `cookie-parser` you also need to enable `type: "module"` in your `package.json` file. This way Node knows that you are using the ES6 syntax instead of CommonJS.

Apart from this, also change the `module` and `moduleResolution` properties in your `tsconfig.json` to NodeNext.

```json
{
   "module": "NodeNext"
   "moduleResolution": "nodenext"
}
```